# How do you group uploads by user using FineUploader?

Tags: php, fine-uploader

The [traditional server](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server/blob/master/handler.php) stores uploaded files `<upload folder>/<uuid>/filename.ext`. If the user uploads multiple files, this creates a directory structure like so:

```
<upload folder>/<uuid1>/filename1.ext
<upload folder>/<uuid2>/filename2.ext
```

Is it possible to combine this such that all files uploaded by the same user are grouped into the same folder? For instance, either

```
<upload folder>/<uuid>/<fileUuid>/filename1.ext
<upload folder>/<uuid>/<fileUuid>/filename2.ext
```

or

```
<upload folder>/<uuid>/filename1.ext
<upload folder>/<uuid>/filename2.ext
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question contains several different references to UUIDs, but it's not clear which UUIDs you are referring to or where these UUIDs are coming from.

Comment: Is there some other way you can phrase your question so I can help you solve this? Also, are you asking for Fine Uploader to send something specific in its requests, or is your question purely how to modify the example PHP server code linked to in your question?

Comment: @RayNicholus sorry for the confusion. in the PHP example, qquuid to set the folder to save files to. This is a unique file identifier. I call this fileUuid above. I'd like to group a users uploads together. Therefore, I'd like to save to userUUid/fileUuid/. This way, things are a little more organized. Is that a little clearer? Thanks

Comment: Would it help to simply include the user's UUID in each file upload request?

Comment: @RayNicholus yes. That'd be great. I assume that would still work with resumable uploads?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the user's UUID is already accessible to your Fine Uploader integration code. You can easily send this value with each upload request by including it as a request parameter in your options:

```
request: {
   params: {
      userUuid: thisUserUuid
   }
}
```

If you need something more dynamic, you can use [the `setParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams) instead.

Server-side, you can use this request parameter to store the file in the appropriate directory, based on the request's qquuid param (the file's uuid) and your passed userUuid param (the user's uuid).

Comment: Is thisUserUuid something I'd have to generate or is it done by FineUploader? If it is done by FineUploader, how is it accessible? I didnt see anything in the docs for it. If not, any recommendations to store one in a similar way/form as fine uploader? Thanks

Comment: Fine Uploader only understands files. Users are out of scope, and something you will need to handle in your app.

Comment: Gotcha. What does fine uploader do so I can set a compatible methodology/cookie? Thanks

Comment: Simply pass your user UUID using the method or option described in my answer. How you get a handle on that user UUID is outside of the scope of Fine Uploader. Could be passed from server to client via ajax request, or perhaps included on your page's markup as part of server-side rendering, or...